# Updating joined tables together results in "multi-part identifier could not be bound"

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, identifier

I am currently trying to update data of two related tables in one query. While it might not be the best idea because of data redundancy, I want to avoid doing a lot of checks for changed data within my application.

These are the tables in use:

```
Process (Id, Name, Description)
FavoriteProcess (Id, Process_Id, Position, CreatedTime)
```

As you see every `FavoriteProcess` entity is related to a `Process` and a `Process` can appear in multiple `FavoriteProcess` entities.

I'm writing a tool with which I can update the `Position` property of a `FavoriteProcess` entity and the `Description` property of the related `Process` as well. For this problem I wrote the following stored procedure which is issuing the error:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateFavoriteProcess
    -- parameters for the stored procedure
    @Id                     int,
    @ProcessDescription     varchar(256),
    @Position               int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- The update query
    UPDATE fp
    SET p.Description = @ProcessDescription, -- this line is issuing the error
        fp.Position = @Position
    FROM FavoriteProcess AS fp
    INNER JOIN Process AS p ON fp.Process_Id = p.Id
    WHERE fp.Id = @Id
END
GO
```

The query is issuing this error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure UpdateFavoriteProcess, Line 13
>   **The multi-part identifier "p.Description" could not be bound**.

I've tried searching for this problem but none of the 5 related SO questions provided a solution that could solve my problem! I tried...

- ...surrounding all tables and columns with []
- ...putting brackets () in any possible way around the join statement

but none of my attempts succeeded. So I'm really thankful for someone who can help me with this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant update two tables at same time

When you start the UPDATE with

```
UPDATE fp
```

You **cant** write

```
SET p.Description
```

That is why you get `Not Bound` error.

Comment: Oh I was sure I read in some question that it's possible to have 2 from-tables in an UPDATE query. I guess that only allows querying data from the joined table but not updating them then...

Answer (score 1):

You could use two separate update statements:

```
UPDATE FavoriteProcess
SET Position = @Position 
WHERE Id = @Id

UPDATE Process  
SET Description = @ProcessDescription
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Process_Id FROM FavoriteProcess WHERE Id = @Id)
```

Comment: Guess that's the only way, yes.